# lsetxattr returns EPERM if attempt to set a value to symlink

Tags: c, linux, filesystems, system-calls

I am testing simple program to add timestamp to xattr.
lsetxattr system call returns error with EPERM. Is that expected behaviour?
How can I set xattr to symlink, not follow the link?

```
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <attr/xattr.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc, char **argv){
    time_t t = time(NULL);
    if(lsetxattr(argv[1], "user.ts", &t, sizeof(time_t), 0) == -1){
        perror(argv[1]);
    }
    return(0);
}
```

example:

```
> ls -l a b c
-rw-r--r-- 1 saka users 0 Feb  1 09:08 a
-rw-r--r-- 1 saka users 0 Feb  1 09:08 b
lrwxrwxrwx 1 saka users 1 Feb  1 09:08 c -> b
> ./ts a
> ./ts c
c: Operation not permitted
```

I tested on 3.10.0-862.14.4.el7.x86_64 with xfs or ext3.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess it's [this](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/latest/source/fs/xattr.c#L121):

```
/*
 * In the user.* namespace, only regular files and directories can have
 * extended attributes. For sticky directories, only the owner and
 * privileged users can write attributes.
 */
```

And in fact, trying to set a `trusted.foo` attribute on a symlink with `lsetxattr(2)` as root works, while a `user.foo` fails with `EPERM`.